# How can I use map in this kind of situation in grails?

Tags: loops, grails, collections, groovy, hashmap

I need to display server info that are running up on ec2. I have managed to display them as a json, but now i only need to display certain fields. The following shows how I am displaying the `statusCode` and `RunType`. Similar concept is applied for other fields.

```
  def check = reservations.each { Reservation reservation ->
        reservation.instances.each() { Instance instance ->
            def code = instance.state
            def StatusCode = code.code
//Get other values


            instance.tags.each() { Tag tag5 ->
                def KeyName2 = tag5.key;
                if (KeyName2 == 'RunType') {
                    def RunType = tag5.value;
                }
            }
       }

instance.tags.each() { Tag tag2 ->

                def KeyName2 = tag2.key;

                if (KeyName2 == 'RunType') {
                    def value2 = tag2.value;                    }
            }

            instance.tags.each() { Tag tag3 ->

                def KeyName3 = tag3.key;

                if (KeyName3 == 'StartedBy') {
                    def value = tag3.value;
                }
            }
```

I wanna obtain something like this to display in my gsp page and loop it for every server.

```
def map = [StatusCode:"80", RunType:"Always", value"test", value2:"abc"]
```

But not sure on how to add values to the map when i obtain them thru the code

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the sort of shape you'd expect the resulting map to be?

Comment: So, you want a List of Maps?  It's quite hard to see what you have and what you want...

Comment: Yes I guess you have to ultimately use list of maps. See my answer below.

Comment: Updated my answer as well ;-)

Comment: If you are still skeptical about the implementation refer this [Sample Groovy Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5684099/) mirroring your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use this:

```
def result = reservations.collectMany { reservation ->
  reservation.instances.collect { instance ->
    [ StatusCode: instance.code,
      RunType   : instance.tags.find { it.key == 'RunType' }?.value,
      StartedBy : instance.tags.find { it.key == 'StartedBy' }?.value ]
  }
}
```

Updated after the update to the question

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like, a statusCode can have multiple `value5`. If that is not the case then you can do something like :

```
def myList = []
def check = reservations.each { Reservation reservation ->
                reservation.instances.each() { Instance instance ->
                def statusCode = instance.state?.code
                def value5 = instance.tags?.find{it.key == 'RunType'}?.value
                myList << ["StatusCode": statusCode, "RunType": value5 ]
           }
      }
```

Note the inner loop is simplified. I am not sure whether it meets your use case scenario since there are inner loops. If you think the map needs to be moved one level down inside the loop then you maintain a list of the key-value pairs (or the map) in the list as well.

The logic can be over-simplified using groovy's `collect` and `inject` functionality.

Comment: StatusCode and Value5 r different fields, I think I confused you. Value5 is runtype.

Comment: Can you show a structured dummy map in the question as to how you want to get at the end?

Comment: Something like the map that I have up there

Comment: @TestUser a list of those maps?

Comment: Ya since there are about 50-60 servers, I think a list of map is what I need